# Uploading file using jquery ajax progress mostly always returning 100 percent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've searched for hours and tried more things than I can count on both hands. But, this is perplexing me.

I'm trying to show upload progress when uploading a file. I'm using the jQuery ajax method to do this while adding in an event listener for the progress. The upload works fine and gets uploaded without any issue. However, the progress is always at 100 right from the start. The only exception to this is if I hit the upload button repeatedly in quick succession in which case it *seems* to show progress. Sometimes this progress will be 50% then 100% within a second on a 25mb file, so not confident this is real progress. Other times it does actually look like it's showing real progress.

I've also tried a pure JavaScript approach and the results are exactly the same.

Any assistance in helping identify why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

**upload_handler.js**

```
$('#upload_form').submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var form = $('#upload_form')[0];
var fd = new FormData(form);


$.ajax({
  xhr: function() {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
      var percent = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
      console.log(percent);
    }, false);
    return xhr;
  },
  url: "https://example.com/upload_file.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: fd,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
})
.done(function(){
  console.log('Done');
})
.fail(function(){
  console.log('Fail');
})
.always(function(){
  console.log('Always');
});
})
```

**Console Output**

When the form is submitted the console will read:

**100** - *this shows immediately when the form is submitted*

**Done** - *this shows a couple seconds after submitting the form*

**Always** - *shows immediately after Done*

**upload_file.php**

```
<?php
$file = $_FILES['file_upload'];

$file_dir = __DIR__ . '/test_uploads/';

if( is_dir( $file_dir ) === false ) {
    mkdir(
        $file_dir,
        0755
    );
}

$file_path = "{$file_dir}{$file['name']}";


if( move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $file_path ) ) {
    error_log("File uploaded to {$file_path}");
    echo 'success';
} else {
    error_log("Failed to upload file to {$file_path}");
    echo 'failed';
}
```

**EDIT**

1. The files above are on a server. So, I wouldn't expect a 25mb file to instantly upload when the file is originating from my computer (I don't pay for that kind of internet...)
2. Uploading larger files 2gb does show progress. Is there anyway to get these smaller file sizes to show progress?

Comment: Try it with a 2G file... 25Mb locally isn't as much as you might think.  Note: `progress` is the `send` process to the server.  `.done` is when your front-end has received the response from the server.  So there will always be a delay between 100% and done as that's the time your php runs and gets back to the client (not just your code, but the service to initiate your code and pass all the data, such as the file content).

Comment: @freedomn-m This isn't being developed locally. The upload file is on my computer and the JS and PHP files are on a server. I will try a larger file just to tick that off the list. Thanks!

Comment: @freedomn-m The 2G file did report progress. It's still uploading, but I expect it to fire the done callback when it reaches 100%. Any ideas why the 25mb file is instantly reported at 100% even though it doesn't show up in the file system until the done event? Question has been updated.